# How to update a record from 2 tables but it will have to meet the condition first?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to update a column in a table from getting records in 2 other table but it will have to meet 4 conditions.

```
Table1:
    Caller_company |  client_id | risk_weight_factor | area_id
        Potter     |       3    |         5          |    1
        Potter     |       3    |         7          |    2

Table2:
    Locate_request_id | caller_company | area_id
         7755329      |   Potter       |    1
         7769761      |   Potter       |    3

Table3:
    Locate_request_id | client_id | risk_factor
         7755329      |    3      |      2
         7769761      |    3      |      4
```

Conditions:

1. table1.locate_request_id = table3.locate_request_id
2. table3.client_id = 3
3. table2.area_id = 1
4. table2.caller_company = 'potter'

If the conditions are met then it will pull the risk_weight_factor value from Table 1 and then update table3.risk_factor column by adding the table1.risk_weight_factor with table3.risk_factor

> table3.risk_factor = table3.risk_factor +
>   table1.risk_weight_factor

```
UPDATE table3
SET [risk_factor] = table3.risk_factor + table1.risk_weight_factor
WHERE table2.locate_request_id = table3.locate_request_id
and 
table3.dpra_client_id = 3
and
table2.lac_area_id = 1
(
table1.caller_company LIKE 'potter' THEN table3.risk_factor+table1.risk_weight_factor);
```

I am very new to SQL and I know my statement does not make sense.  If anyone can help with this, I will greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
Update T3
set T3.risk_factor=T3.risk_factor+T1.risk_weight_factor
from
table3 T3
inner join table2 T2 on T2.Locate_request_id=T3.Locate_request_id
inner join table1 T1 on T1.area_id=T2.area_id
where
T3.client_id = 3 and
T2.area_id = 1 and
T2.caller_company = 'potter'
```

The joins will return the value matched in the table and the where clause will take the odd one out.

Answer (score 0):

Your update  statement in the 4th condition has something more than what your condition is specified . if the condition you specified are true then the udpate statement would be something like this :

```
UPDATE table3
SET [risk_factor] = table3.risk_factor + table1.risk_weight_factor
WHERE table2.locate_request_id = table3.locate_request_id
and 
table3.dpra_client_id = 3
and
table2.lac_area_id = 1
and
table1.caller_company = 'potter'
```